# how to display drop down menus on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Can someone explain how can i make this drop down menu work when the user tabs on the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/NnCVv/234/

```
<ul id="drop-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="html.html" tabindex="0">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>



 ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul li a:hover {background: #f00;}
  li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li {float: none;}
  li:hover a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
  li:focus ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you add `tabindex` and also add the proper CSS styles to your `li` elements, it'll work: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NnCVv/236/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul id="drop-nav">
  <li tabindex="1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li tabindex="2"><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="html.html" tabindex="0">HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
  ul {list-style: none;padding: 0px;margin: 0px;}
  ul li {display: block;position: relative;float: left;border:1px solid #000}
  li ul {display: none;}
  ul li a {display: block;background: #000;padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;text-decoration: none;
           white-space: nowrap;color: #fff;}
  ul li a:hover,ul li:focus a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover ul,li:focus ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
  li:hover li,li:focus li {float: none;}
  li:hover a,li:focus a {background: #f00;}
  li:hover li a:hover,li:focus li a:hover {background: #000;}
  #drop-nav li ul li {border-top: 0px;}
```

Comment: Thanks...now display what is under item 2, is there a way to make the next tab be HTMl them CSS ...

Comment: sorry but I can't understand what you said! :-s

Comment: if you navigate the menu using the keyboard when i get to Item 2 which is the one that has something under it only shows what is on it, and if you press tab again the menu disappears...

Comment: I'm afraid you're gonna need to use js for that, and it is a whole different story!

Answer (score 0):

It will work once you include this:

```
<script src="jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
```